# Android how to get supported network types

Tags: android, android-networking

I read many posts about getting the current network type, but i'm interested in all supported network types. Is there a way to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectivityManager` has methods for this

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (NetworkInfo network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo()) {
    Log.d("Network", "network info: " + network.getType() + " " + network.getTypeName());
}
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo()

> Returns connection status information about all network types supported by the device.

Also add to manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`